# Open Weather Map api key not working (i guess)

Tags: python, openweathermap

some time ago i created a program that tells you current temperature in your city using pyowm module, and it worked great, until now

I thought it might be cause of the API key that you get from the site, so i generated new key and its still not working

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('my API key') # doesn't work beyond this point
data = Get_Location() # gets your current location
location = data[4] # city name

weatherloc = owm.weather_at_place(location)
status = weatherloc.get_weather()
temperature = status.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
weather = status.get_detailed_status()
main_weather = status.get_status()
temp_out = f"and outside temperature is {temperature}{degree} celsius."
print(temp_out)
```

its pretty basic thing, but the program just stops after "owm" line, no error messages or anything, it just stops

Edit: Forgot to put "print" when showing the code

Comment: What do yo expect this code to do? If you wanted to output `temp_out`, then you can do this with `print(temp_out)`

Comment: I expect it to work as it did till today, but it just stops after first line, i put some random prints in between these lines to see where the problem is and found out it is after "owm = pyowm.OWM('my API key')"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the request module instead? it costs much more shorter code than that